# Firestore rule allow read condition timestamp problem

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firestore for the first time and I have a problem, I want to allow read if the message was send less than 5 minutes but it doesn't work.

`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /locations/{allDocuments=**} {
      allow read: if request.time < Timestamp.fromMillis(resource.data.timestamp) + duration.time(0, 5, 0, 0)
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}`

Every data has a child call "timestamp" and the value is a number like "1554710156002"

With this read condition my app can't read anything but it can write.
Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: What exactly is the timestamp field in your document? Is it a timestamp type field? What is the query you're using?  Also please edit the question to show the entire rule, not just one line of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `duration.time(hours, minutes, seconds, nanos)` (documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.duration_)) to manipulate [timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp):

```
duration.time(0, 5, 0, 0)
```

Also, my personal preference is to put the duration after the (fixed) resource creation time, which makes reasoning about it a bit easier for me.

Your code would become

```
allow read: if request.time < resource.data.timestamp + duration.time(0, 5, 0, 0);
```

(NB: I did not verify this, and this is assuming your timestamp is actually a [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp))

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried and it doesn't work :(

Comment: In my data ther is a child named timestamp, the value is a number like "1554710156002"

Comment: You can convert it to a timestamp using [Timestamp.fromMillis](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#.fromMillis)(resource.data.timestamp)

Comment: But then there is not much difference with your original question, so something else must be wrong. As @Doug-Stevenson indicated, we might need the entire rule to assess the problem, not just this one line with the `allow read`.

Comment: Maybe the missing `;` at the end of the `allow read: ... ;` is causing trouble?

Answer (score 0):

The controlling of read/write/update rights for users within a Firestore database is achieved via Firestore security rules that you would configure from within the Firebase console.